# KQL Private Endpoint Bytes In\Out

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to create a KQL query which is to capture all private endpoints and see if the bytes in or out equal null (0), however when I runa  query for private endpoints all I get is basic infomration.

```
Resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.network/privateendpoints'
| mvexpand ProvisioningState = properties.provisioningState
| mvexpand PLSprop = properties.networkInterfaces
| mvexpand PLSprop = properties.networkInterfaces
| mvexpand PLSprop2 = properties.subnet
```

Is there a way to get bytes in or out ad their values, or any that equal 0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Documentation typo ("out" instead of "in") has been fixed

###### [Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftnetworkprivateendpoints)

| Metric | Exportable via Diagnostic Settings? | Metric Display Name | Unit | Aggregation Type | Description | Dimensions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PEBytesIn | Yes | Bytes In | Count | Total | Total number of Bytes In* | No Dimensions |
| PEBytesOut | Yes | Bytes Out | Count | Total | Total number of Bytes Out | No Dimensions |

Comment: Kind reminder to check the answer